# Sprockets not loading when using Rspec with Rails mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-engines, sprockets

I generated a fresh Rails engine project using the generator:

```
rails plugin new my_engine --full --mountable \
--dummy-path spec/dummy --skip-test-unit
```

I'm try to set up a Rails engine that I can test with Rspec, so rather than using the standard `test/dummy` path, it uses `spec/dummy` to fit Rspec conventions. After I get this set up, I'm unable to run the dummy app because of this error:

```
/home/user/sites/engines/blog/spec/dummy/config/application.rb:9
:in `require': cannot load such file -- sprockets/railtie (LoadError)
from /home/user/sites/engines/blog/spec/dummy/config/application.rb:9
:in `<top (required)>'
```

Looking at the application.rb file within the dummy app, I tried switching the individual require statements (generated because of the `--skip-test-unit` option) to the standard `require rails/all`. This allowed me to start the application, but sure enough the `application.js` and `application.css` files were not rendered.

```
Started GET "/javascripts/application.js" for 128.104.84.149 
at 2015-02-03 09:06:29 -0600
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] 
"/javascripts/application.js"):
```

This error does not occur when I do the standard engine generation:

```
rails plugin new my_engine --full --mountable
```

It's also not a problem if I plug the engine into another app set up with Rspec. What could be the problem with loading sprockets when the dummy application is in the `spec/dummy` directory instead of `test/dummy`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm currently stumped on it, myself.

Comment: Unfortunately no. For now I'm just keeping the dummy in `test/dummy` and my specs in `spec`.